# Python upload an Image form my hard drive and show it on a canvas wideget.

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am writing a small python program that upload an image from A SPECIFIC location in my computer and then show it on a canvas wideget. I am using Tkinter as a GUI.

Problem: I need to upload the image from any location in my computer. I need to create a window explorer (similar to the one windows has Ctr + O) that let you browse through your folders to find the image you want to upload.

Question: What is the best way or module to create the Open Window explorer.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a handy module for that: tkFileDialog!

```
import tkFileDialog
tkFileDialog.askopenfilename()
```

The function will return the path to the file for you and theres a variety of options you can set [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/tkinter-file-dialogs.htm)